# d3 svg charts on ie8 (Windows XP)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, svg, raphael, d3.js

Has anyone had any success in making d3.js (svg) to work on ie8 (Windows XP version: 8.0.6001.18702)?

The [d34raphael](http://webmonarch.github.com/d34raphael/examples.html) solution works for IE8 on Windows 7(version:8.0.7601.17514) . However IE8 on Windows XP ( 8.0.6001.18702) is different, and d34raphael doesn't work with this version.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend r2d3.js

https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/

Make sure to read the README to make it function properly.

Answer (score 0):

r2d3 not support image and text very well,

i recommend :

https://github.com/shawnbot/aight

Comment: Please add synopsis to your answer. Links-Only answers are discouraged on SO