# How to use D3 and R2D3 in IE8

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-8, d3.js, treemap

I searched online about the problem of using d3.js SVG under IE8, and I find an ideal method is using **R2D3**, and I tried to do like that, but it still doesn't work yet.
I am not sure what I have tried is right, do I only need to import the library like that?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>R2D3 101</title>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="r2d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script src="d3.js"></script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

And other things don't need to change?  If you are interested, I can show you a simple demo about my treemap function.
http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/cR35x/9/

At first, I am thinking about if it is the problem of the limitations using **Transforms** as mentioned in the github: https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/

But the thing is, I really write the function as the GOOD one:

```js
// BAD
circles.transform('translate(20)');

// GOOD
circles.transform('translate(20,0)');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [D3 IE8 Compatibility?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202118/d3-ie8-compatibility)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d3 svg charts on ie8 (Windows XP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480588/d3-svg-charts-on-ie8-windows-xp)